# Generating DataURI from uploaded picture and add to PDF (JsPDF)

Tags: javascript, base64, jspdf

I am uploading a picture to the server, then my script converts it to data URI. It all works fine, in the setTimeOut function the alert displays the dataURI just fine, but the addImage function in the next line doesn't seem to add the picture to the PDF. The addImage function in the last line adds another image just fine.

I have tried everything, dont understand why the addImage function inside the setTimeOut block doesn't add the image to the PDF.

Live version: http://www.course0001.com/fiverr/lifemax/004/

```
if( document.getElementById("field_file").files.length == 0 ){
doc.addImage(logoData, 'JPEG', 65, 35, 87, 27); // Add logo

} else {

  let fnm = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
  let fileExtension = getExtension(fnm);

  var logo = null;
  getDataUri('/fiverr/lifemax/004/backend/logos/logo-'+uniqueFileName+'.'+fileExtension, function(dataUri) {
    logo = dataUri;
    console.log("logo=" + logo);
  });

  function getDataUri(url, cb)
  {
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    image.onload = function () {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

      //next three lines for white background in case png has a transparent background
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';  /// set white fill style
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      cb(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    };
    image.src = url;
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    alert(logo); // This displays the data URI fine
    doc.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', 65, 35, 87, 27); // This never adds the image, however the alert displays the dataURI fine. 
  }, 3000);

}

doc.addImage(coverData, 'JPEG', 10, 95, 190, 190); // This adds the image just fine. Data URI is stored in a variable as string.
```

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF is an asynchronous function meaning it does not wait for your previous set of lines to be executed fully.

When you call **addImage** in "setTimeout" (Which also executes after 3000ms without waiting for the dependency to fully load), the logo may not have been rendered yet. And thus, the white image.

But the next line does not get executed before the "coverData" is fully rendered, and thus you see it on PDF.

You may try the below code to make is synchronous.

```
if( document.getElementById("field_file").files.length == 0 ){
doc.addImage(logoData, 'JPEG', 65, 35, 87, 27); // Add logo

} else {

  let fnm = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
  let fileExtension = getExtension(fnm);

  var logo = null;
  getDataUri('/fiverr/lifemax/004/backend/logos/logo-'+uniqueFileName+'.'+fileExtension, function(dataUri) {
    logo = dataUri;
    console.log("logo=" + logo);
    setLogo(logo);
  });

  function getDataUri(url, cb)
  {
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    image.onload = function () {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

      //next three lines for white background in case png has a transparent background
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';  /// set white fill style
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      cb(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    };
    image.src = url;
  }

  function setLogo(logo){
    alert(logo); // This displays the data URI fine
    doc.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', 65, 35, 87, 27); // This never adds the image, however the alert displays the dataURI fine. 
  };

}

doc.addImage(coverData, 'JPEG', 10, 95, 190, 190); // This adds the image just fine. Data URI is stored in a variable as string.
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, finally I solved it with a $( document ).ready function, but I did not fully understand why it helped. I understand it now, big lesson for me for the future, thank you again!

Comment: Glad to here, by using **$( document ).ready** you have made the function wait till the entire document is rendered before execution. Good find.